# Intercept clone using LD_PRELOAD in C, Linux

Tags: c, linux, ld-preload

I want to intercept **clone** calls made by a simple pthread program. I am trying to use the **LD_PRELOAD** to achieve this. But could not get handle to the **clone** calls. When I run strace on pthread program, I can see that

```
clone(child_stack=0x7f15b7fa3ef0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tid=[8895], tls=0x7f15b7fa4640, child_tidptr=0x7f15b7fa4910) = 8895
```

But the clone signature of linux as well as the one I used in shared object is

```
int clone(int (*fn)(void *), void *stack, int flags, void *arg, ...
                 /* pid_t *parent_tid, void *tls, pid_t *child_tid */ );
```

Is the reason for not getting handle to clone is due to the difference in clone signature between straced one and linux manual?

or

LD_PRELOAD is not the correct way to intercept **clone** system calls made by pthread program?

shared object code

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#define _FCNTL_H
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <bits/fcntl.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*_clone_f_t)(int (*fn)(void *), void *stack, int flags, void *arg, ...);
static _clone_f_t _clone_f_ = NULL;
void __attribute__((constructor)) my_init();
void __attribute__((destructor)) my_fini();

void my_init(){
    _clone_f_ = (_clone_f_t)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"clone");
}

void my_fini(){}


int clone(int (*fn)(void *), void *stack, int flags, void *arg, ...){
    printf("called my clone\n");
    va_list arglist;
    pid_t * parent_tid;
    void * tls;
    pid_t * child_tid;
    va_start(arglist,arg);
    parent_tid = va_arg(arglist, pid_t*);
    tls = va_arg(arglist, void*);
    child_tid = va_arg(arglist, pid_t*);
    va_end(arglist);
//removed rest of the code
}
```

compiled it using

**gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o myclone.so myclone.c -ldl**

Comment: `strace` tells you the *syscalls* a process does.  LD_PRELOAD lets you interpose *library function calls*.  The two are not the same.  Use `ltrace` instead of `strace` to track library function calls, so you can find out the correct function you need to interpose.  (I expect it to be `pthread_create()`, which is implemented within the C library using the 'clone' syscall; not as a call to the `clone()` C library function.)  To intercept syscalls, you'll probably need to (write a program to) ptrace the target process instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to intercept clone calls made by a simple pthread program.

If you disassemble `libpthread.so.0` (the `do_clone()` function), you'll discover that it doesn't call `clone()`, it calls `__clone()`.

You can also observe this in `nm -D libpthread.so.0` output:

```
nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 | grep clone
                 U __clone@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Changing `myclone.c` to provide `int __clone(...)` on a system with GLIBC 2.31 results in:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./myclone.so ./a.out
called my clone
```

---

Note that the code you commented out:

```
//removed rest of the code
```

is severely restricted in what it can do -- this code is called while holding several GLIBC-internal locks, the newly-created thread has not been fully initialized, etc. etc.

If you call into GLIBC at that point, you should expect deadlocks, crashes and/or mystery bugs.